# User defined type guard on outer type / nested property?

Tags: typescript

I have a question related to [user defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), in particular whether it is possible to implement a *predicate function* that serves as a type guard for a sub field.

Consider the following example:

```
type ContentFoo = {
  kind: "foo";
  foo: string;
}

type ContentBar = {
  kind: "bar";
  bar: string;
}

type Content = ContentFoo | ContentBar;
```

Defining a type guard directly on a `content: Content` works just fine, e.g.:

```
function isFooContent(content: Content): content is ContentFoo {
  return content.kind === "foo";
}
```

Now imagine `Content` is wrapped into an another type like:

```
type Entry = {
  id: string;
  content: Content;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to define a type guard based on this `Entry` wrapper type. My naive guess was:

```
function isFooEntry(entry: Entry): entry.content is ContentFoo {
  return entry.content.kind === "foo";
}
```

However the compiler doesn't like the syntax of such a predicate function:

```
Cannot find namespace 'entry'.
```

Is there any other way to write a predicate function that operates "one level up"? Or is such a predicate function impossible by design, because the TypeScript compiler cannot track the types via an outer type?

---

The intended use is:

```
if (isFooEntry(entry)) {
  console.log("It must have a foo", entry.content.foo)
}
```

instead of having to write

```
if (isFooContent(entry.content)) {
  console.log("It must have a foo", entry.content.foo)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about how you'd use this function? `isFooEntry()`, I mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2BJAxOcoF4oG8CwAUFFANYCWCAJgFxQBEAZhvQNxEnNx0DOwATpQDm7QgF8iRUJFiJkSAEIBDftjwcylWgwBGKthr39eA4aImEp4aPCQpga2-ODpMAH1l3FK0VZkBRJH4QNQJiKHJtPkEEEQ0AYzl7Oid7c0lCRgBXBHjgckQInldAgRAACntgulLggEo6KpDyHigAeQBbcmAAHlqQABooAHJEr2BhgD4oADI8KDHnFKS0DCgxdXD%20CGAs-gQoJoA6RfsjimpsLBwmFnTLQjG%20KCUaoJCcXAjtemQ%20eiGpyQdC%20Fx%20XABUC4dHoqDabRYYjEvkI5EYUHKLRK73KSjqdU2JBITzgABsIEdSXAhLiTitgEcuHUiBYiE8HDo3mVQt8YX9gJCgcAQZpqDCjJCjDCFABBGX8BX0JEotEYrEYfrlHT4wlE4AAC34cAA7lAEBBTf4FXB%20OVhgBVBDbJTxfVKHTk4bM8RAA)

```
function isFooEntry(entry: Entry): entry is Omit<Entry, 'content'> & { content: ContentFoo } {
  return entry.content.kind === "foo";
}
```

Comment: Nice thanks! Now I can parse it: `Omit<Entry, 'content'>` first "removes" the property from the `Entry` type, and the `& { content: ContentFoo }` brings it back but now under the explicit `ContentFoo` type. Makes sense.

Comment: @bluenote10 You can extract `Omit<Entry, 'content'> & { content: ContentFoo }` to an `EntryFoo` type to simplify the signature.